# Messed up bucket policy and not able to access the bucket anymore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I created an s3 bucket and gave the following bucket policy to it

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1586942250763",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1586942249918",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accID:user/username1”
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Obviously this would give access only to the user username1. Now username1 was deleted from IAM. Is there any way to recover access to this bucket. I have an IAM account with admin privileges but `aws s3api delete-bucket-policy111` seems to be not working.

Comment: If your admin account has Console access, you should be able to visit the S3 section, click on the bucket name, and then click Permissions > Bucket Policy. You can then edit or delete the policy as needed.

Comment: No, for that also, I'm having permission denied error. The original bucket policy is blocking it I guess

Answer (score 0):

Only root user can do anything on that bucket now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility, that you have multiple accounts and the bucket belong to another account. Try if other accounts see the bucket.